# AspNetCore.Identity manage account header text change

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-identity

[image: header text]

Hi,

I created login on my app using [Scaffolding Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-identity-into-an-mvc-project-without-existing-authorization).
After the forder structure was added, I was able to modify all but the header of the page.

[image: folder structure]

I opened up each cshtml file did not find the header text `Change your account settings` in any of them.

Can someone help me to locate the header?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/503636/aspnetcoreidentity-manage-account-header-text-chan.html?childToView=504066#comment-504066

Refer to above, when I created Identity pages, I did not select all but only things that I wanted in the scaffoling options. As a result I did not have `Account\Manage\Layout` during scaffolding, did not have `_Layout.cshtml` file to override default view from `AspNetCore.Identity`.